# Mean by group, exclude some rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

I have a below table and want to calculate mean by state, I would like to calculate mean only for the rows which has 1 as customer

| Customer | State | Score | Output_Mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | GA | 1 |  |
| 1 | GA | 2 | 2.5 |
| 1 | GA | 3 | 2.5 |
| 1 | NY | 9 | 8 |
| 1 | NY | 7 | 8 |
| 0 | DC | 6 |  |
| 0 | DC | 4 |  |

I have below code, how do I add customer criteria?

`df['output_mean'] = (df.fillna({'state':'missing'}).groupby(['state'])['score'].transform(lambda x: x.mean()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just update where you want:

```
customer_1 = df['Customer'].eq(1)
df.loc[customer_1, 'Output_Mean'] = df[customer_1].groupby('State')['Score'].transform('mean')
```

For most (later) Pandas versions, you can forgo the `customer_1` on the left hand side and do:

```
df['Output_Mean'] = df[customer_1].groupby('State')['Score'].transform('mean')
```

Or just a `query` without mask:

```
df['Output_Mean'] = df.query('Customer == 1').groupby('State')['Score'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
   Customer State  Score  Output_Mean
0         0   GA       1          NaN
1         1   GA       2          2.5
2         1   GA       3          2.5
3         1   NY       9          8.0
4         1   NY       7          8.0
5         0   DC       6          NaN
6         0   DC       4          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include a mask for `customer==1` in the `groupby` (along with `State`) and use `np.where` to assign values to `df['output_mean']`:

```
mask = df['Customer']==1
df['output_mean'] = np.where(mask, df.fillna({'State':'missing'}).groupby([mask,'State'])['Score'].transform('mean'), np.nan)
```

Output:

```
   Customer State  Score  output_mean
0         0    GA      1          NaN
1         1    GA      2          2.5
2         1    GA      3          2.5
3         1    NY      9          8.0
4         1    NY      7          8.0
5         0    DC      6          NaN
6         0    DC      4          NaN
```